# How to edit HIVE Table Parameters?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have created a HIVE table through pyspark in ORC format and everything is working as per the requirement. 
However, when I observed the details o fthe HIVE table, I see below

```
describe formatted <tbl_name>;
```

I get below output

```
Table Parameters:
        COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE   false
        EXTERNAL                FALSE
        numFiles                99
        numRows                 -1
        rawDataSize             -1
```

How can I change the value of "COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE" while writing the code in pyspark? IS there any way to do that? If no, then is there a way to change it after the table has been created?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ANALYZE TABLE`:

```
spark.sql("ANALYZE TABLE foo COMPUTE STATISTICS")
```

but please remember, that Spark output in general, provides only partial Hive compatibility.